# flip view not responding for swipe gesture emilsjolander/android-FlipView implementing Gridview/listview

Tags: android, flipview

I am implementing Gridview in one of the flip page using emilsjolander/android-FlipView ,

my issues is unable to go to next page or previous , randomly once in 5 swipes it works . I know this is due to touch intercept issue which is not propagating from gridview to flipview . any fix will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

### GridView inside FlipView :

I also had the same problem, but resolved it by making Gridview as non-interseptable. You have write your own class extending Gridview like this,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class NotinterceptableGrid extends GridView {

public NotinterceptableGrid(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean ret = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    if (ret)
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    return ret;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean ret = super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    if (ret)
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    return ret;
}
```

}

`

and in xml layout file, replace GridView tag with this newly added Custom GridView,thats it. it will work now. for listView class you have extend ListView.